# How to embed image with email template (ejs file) in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I am new to sending mail in express.js. I want to use a logo in my mail template in ejs file. But error appears saying attachments is not defined. Without attachment the mail is working.

**My code :**

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const path = require("path");
const ejs = require("ejs");
sendMail = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("controller");
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "tanjibrubyat@gmail.com",
      pass: "qaaqcvbjgnyrhgrr",
    },
     attachments: [
       {
         filename: "image.png",
         path: "../../../public/images/b2cde6d6-a2fa-439a-b06f-1bf93360760f.jpg",
         cid: "unique@nodemailer.com", //same cid value as in the html img src
       },
     ],
  });
  const type = req.body.type;
  const text = req.body.text;
  const name = req.body.name;
  const student_id = req.body.student_id;
  const lead_id = req.body.lead_id;
  let info;
  let file = path.join(__dirname, "../../../views/skilled.ejs");

  const data = await ejs.renderFile(file, {
    text,
    type,
    name,
    student_id,
    lead_id,
  });
    
  const recipient = [req.body.to];
  for (let i = 0; i < recipient.length; i++) {
    info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: "tanjibrubyat@gmail.com",
      to: recipient[i],
      subject: req.body.subject,
      html: data,
      
    });
  }
```

**Problems I am facing:

1. Error - attachments is not defined.
2. How to pass the cid value to ejs file ?**

Please help.